# English word for "Bold/Italic/Underlined"?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm writing some technical documentation for a rendering engine we're developing. One paragraph says:

> The style includes font settings, such as typeface, size, bold, italic, underlined.

Is there a single word that describes the "bold, italic, underlined" traits, so I can write

> The style includes font settings, such as typeface, size, {single word}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically a single font family may consist of individual fonts in plain, bold, italic, bold italic, and other variants.

However, this is a duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97081/what-is-the-typography-term-which-refers-to-the-usage-of-bold-italics-and-unde), to which the answer is [typographical emphasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emphasis_%28typography%29).